# Highcharts - tooltip triggers very slow on element hover

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I need to setup highcharts with a tooltip that triggers on hover over an icon that is part of the chart title. I have used options:

```
title: {
  useHTML: true,
  text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Arbeidsmarkedsintegrasjon'
},
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mu9wswv3/) is the working example.

The way it is setup now, tooltip triggers very slowly, it takes few seconds to see the tooltip text. I am wondering how to set it up so that it triggers immediately on hover.

Comment: tooltip shows fast for me

Comment: But is that the one that you get when you hover over question mark icon?

Comment: @Marco, you mean the extended text on the chart title tooltip? Not the data point highcharts.tooltip.

Comment: @Marco oh I got it. hovering over question mark triggers default browser title with standart delay.

Comment: @Denis how to change that delay?

Comment: @Marco as far as I know it is not possible with default title. You may create pseudoelement :after { content: attr(title); display: none; } and reveal it on hover

Comment: @Denis would it be too much of a problem if you could post an example?

Comment: This question is very misleading - this has nothing to do with a Highcharts tooltip.  This is an HTML element help text issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few options here:

1. Using foundation, as far as I can see you've used `.has-tip` class which is from Zurb Foundation
   http://jsfiddle.net/mu9wswv3/9/
   p.s. dunno why arrow styles are broken
2. Or using pseudoelement

   ```
   .has-tip{
     position: relative;
   }

   .has-tip:after {
     display: none;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     font-size: .7em;
     content: attr(data-title);
     position: absolute;
     background: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.85098);
     border: 1px solid rgb(124, 181, 236);
     padding: 5px;
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
     transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
   }

   .has-tip:hover:after {
     display: block;
   }
   ```

   p.s. title must be replaced with data-title in this case

   http://jsfiddle.net/sLhmxtko/